# Sumar dias a objeto tipo DateTime

Tags: php

Tengo una fecha de tipo DateTime:

```
$entrada = new \DateTime($request->get('entrada'));
```

Necesito obtener otra fecha del mismo tipo sumados n dias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `DateInterval` para agregar la cantidad de días que necesites. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
$fecha = new \DateTime('2018-12-07');
$agregarDias = 10;
$fecha->add(new \DateInterval("P{$agregarDias}D"));
echo $fecha->format('Y-m-d'); // 2018-12-17
```

El link de la ducumentación oficial es: http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 0):

espero que el siguiente código te sirva

```
$fechauno='2018-09-27';
            $fecha = strtotime(date($fechauno));
            $start=$fecha;
            while (date ("$date",$start)>+1)
            {
                $start-=86400;
            }
            //for para obtener la segunda fecha
            for  ($i=7; $i <8; $i++)
            {
                //aquí se hace la suma de N días para obtener el resultado que se desea obtener 
             $fechados=date("Y-m-d",$start+ ($i*86400));?><br><?php
            }
```